# Sketch rendering colors in wrong way for PNG and PDF

Tags: color, sketch-app, mockup, subpixel-rendering

Sketch has been showing wrong colors when importing vector images (PDF format) and images (PNG format). I've noticed this several times. Has anyone else faced a similar issue?

I followed this link, https://sketchapp.com/docs/other/color-management/, changed color from `Unmanaged` to `sRGB` but the problem still persists.

Comment: Have you recently updated to High Sierra on a Mac?

Comment: @Confused, Yes. Version 10.13.4 Beta

Comment: This is the same version I'm running. I've noticed a lot of previews of old graphics I've made are completely wrongly coloured in this and the last beta. This is quite probably causing the same problem in Sketch.

Comment: When I open them in Photoshop, they're the correct colours. But Preview and Finder are showing them utterly washed out, and way too bright, and slightly shifted in Hue, too. I think. I'm glad I'm not the only one.

Comment: This doesn't happen for documents that I've made since these two updates. Only for things I've made in the past. Most noticeable on .png files that were made in Windows with 3ds Max. They're so blown out I can't even really see what's in them.

Comment: I've been opening them fine in Preview, perhaps because they were created after I updated to the last few versions. On the other hand, when I open pdf files in Sketch (particularly those exported from AI) I see them as if the negative effect was applied and in png files, I see the washed out/ too bright  behavior you described

Comment: Ouch. I'm lucky to not be using Sketch. And feel sorry for you. Not sure how to even search for information about this on Apple forums. It hasn't bothered me enough to search it out, either. But your question's mention of PNG made me curious to see if it was a blight affecting others.

Answer (score 1):

With the washed out effect, I noticed it too — suspiciously right after updating to High Sierra. Luckily, there's a fix. And it has to deal with macOS gamma values.

---

## Sketch Gamma Correction Plugin

I don't know why Sketch doesn't bundle this into Sketch itself, but they released a [Gamma Correction plugin](https://www.sketchapp.com/support/troubleshooting/gamma-fix-high-sierra) to fix it.

**Here's a description of the issue, and how the plugin fixes it:**

> We’ve identified an issue where bitmap images that are exported and re-imported into Sketch are appearing incorrectly and appearing washed out.
>
> This is because macOS High Sierra renders certain gamma values in bitmaps differently to previous macOS versions.
>
> If you’re using Sketch 47, we’ve fixed this bug already and all images exported from Sketch will have the correct gamma values and should render correctly. If you’re using Sketch 46 or earlier this bug will be fixed when you update.
>
> However, if you’re creating and exporting bitmap images in other software and importing them into Sketch, you may still see issues with washed out colors.
>
> To fix this, we’ve created a plugin that you can run on any Sketch documents that aren’t rendering properly. Simply click the link below to download the plugin, install it and run it once on each affected document. Please note, this plugin is only compatible with Sketch 47 or later.

And [here's the page you can download it from.](https://www.sketchapp.com/support/troubleshooting/gamma-fix-high-sierra)

Comment: I tried this beforehand, but no luck. Didn't fix it for me :/ I am using Sketch 49

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. It did the trick for me ‍♂️

Comment: In my case seems to only be the issue with images exported previously from Sketch, all other bitmap shows fine. If I export the image, open it with Photoshop and save it again, Sketch shows it correctly. This flow however is not very desirable. I also installed the gamma correction plugin. Anyone any luck on this?